# Can we able to pass list as an argument for navigation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: list, kotlin, retrofit2, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Actually, I need to pass 'emptylist'  to all screens in navigation, through arguments. But I couldn't find any type called 'ListType' in NavType. How can I pass the list to all screens?

```
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
        composable(
            Screen.HomeScreen.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("empList"){
                       type= NavType.ListType //Actually there is no ListType in NavType
                }
            )
        ) {
            HomeScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(Screen.EmloyeeListScreen.route) {
            EmployeeList(navController)
        }
        composable(Screen.EmployeeDetailsScreen.route) {
            EmplyoeeDetails(navController)
        }
        composable(Screen.ProductScreen.route) {
            ProductScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```